# How to make 32bit and 64bit iso image together under 64bit debian using simple-cdd?

Tags: simple-cdd

I have been using simple-cdd for about one month. I built some custom 64bit debian iso images successfully however now I need to build an iso for 32bit systems aswell under 64bit debian if possible. Otherwise I need to setup new 32bit host to build it and have to manage and syncronise two systems and configs in every aspect. Is it possible to create a multi arch iso with simple-cdd and/or is it possible create separate images for 32 and 64 bit systems under 64bit host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if that's still an issue for you but wanted to give a hint because I was in same situation today and found a solution for me, which builds a hybrid iso for i386 and amd64...

Either export this before executing `build-simple-cdd` or put the whole line in your `simple-cdd.conf`:

```
export ARCHES="i386 amd64"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had tried this but I was not successful. What is your arch running simple-cdd? Do I need to install any other helper package(s) to make x86 and amd64 arch CDs?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I realized that somehow I had tried `export ARCHES="i586"` so it works with `export ARCHES="i386 amd64"`. Thank you again.